# Unsubscribe first observable in switchmap

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I have two observables, the second need the result of the first, so I used [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) :

```
this.fooSharer.getFoo().pipe(switchMap((foo: Foo) => {
    return this.http.post('/someUrl',
    body,
    headers
  )
}));
```

So I have in return an Observable of Object (from http.post), but my subscription from the foo Observale is still active and I can't unsubscribe, how can I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use emitted value from `fooSharer.getFoo()` just as a signal to start the second Observable you can put `take(1)` just before the `switchMap`.
This way, after the first emitted value the `fooSharer.getFoo()` will complete.